# Firebase updateChildValue for multiple locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to `updateChildValue` for multiple `child`s ? Like in the following example but with single transaction. Keep `key3` intact

```
/*
user = {
    user1 : {
        key1 : -1,
        key2 : -1,
        key3 : 111,
    },
    user2 : {
        key1 : -1,
        key2 : -1,
        key3 : 111,
    },
}
*/

NSDictionary <NSString *, NSNumber *> *dictionary = @{
    @"key1" : @111,
    @"key2" : @111,
};

FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

[[ref
    child:@"user1"]
    updateChildValues:dictionary];

[[ref
    child:@"user2"]
    updateChildValues:dictionary];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same result from a single call to `updateChildValues`, expand the dictionary to contain all updates ad their full paths:

```
NSDictionary <NSString *, NSNumber *> *dictionary = @{
    @"user1/key1" : @111,
    @"user1/key2" : @111,
    @"user2/key1" : @111,
    @"user2/key2" : @111,
};

FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

[ref
    updateChildValues:dictionary];
```

Also see the [Firebase blog post introducing multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html).